# How to hide some logs from spring boot startup via log4j

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j

I want to hide any log from 3rd party jar in the spring boot startup log, especially for `springfox.documentation` because they are creating so many useless logs like `CachingOperationNameGenerator`

```
$ java -jar target/app.jar
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

 APP API

 > keep log clean
 > [yyyyMMdd:HHmmssSSS][thread][level][message]
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________


2020-07-15 23:22:14.810  INFO 47784 --- [           main] i.i.c.CaseMarketplaceApplication         : Starting CaseMarketplaceApplication v0.0.1 on LOCAL-PC with PID 47784
2020-07-15 23:22:14.814  INFO 47784 --- [           main] i.i.c.CaseMarketplaceApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-07-15 23:22:16.869  INFO 47784 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-07-15 23:22:17.059  INFO 47784 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 175ms. Found 18 repository interfaces.
2020-07-15 23:22:18.747  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2020-07-15 23:22:18.780  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-07-15 23:22:18.781  INFO 47784 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2020-07-15 23:22:18.884  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-07-15 23:22:18.884  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4004 ms
2020-07-15 23:22:20.071  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default...]
2020-07-15 23:22:20.228  INFO 47784 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2020-07-15 23:22:20.231  INFO 47784 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-07-15 23:22:20.515  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-07-15 23:22:20.878  INFO 47784 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-07-15 23:22:21.322  INFO 47784 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-07-15 23:22:21.341  INFO 47784 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2020-07-15 23:22:31.679  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
2020-07-15 23:22:31.690  INFO 47784 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : 
2020-07-15 23:22:34.988  INFO 47784 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-07-15 23:22:35.626  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2020-07-15 23:22:36.590  WARN 47784 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : 
2020-07-15 23:22:36.849  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-07-15 23:22:37.094  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/api/v1/login/*'], []
2020-07-15 23:22:37.094  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/api/v1/version/ping'], []
2020-07-15 23:22:37.094  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/v2/api-docs'], []
2020-07-15 23:22:37.094  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/configuration/ui'], []
2020-07-15 23:22:37.094  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/swagger-resources'], []
2020-07-15 23:22:37.095  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/configuration/security'], []
2020-07-15 23:22:37.151  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@43045f9f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@22a736d7, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@508a65bf, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@25290bca, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter@7a560583, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@66273da0, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter@37052337, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter@4d722ac9, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7f353d99, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@38d17d80, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter@53f0a4cb, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1e58512c, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4ac86d6a, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@26dc9bd5]
2020-07-15 23:22:37.179  INFO 47784 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2020-07-15 23:22:37.441  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-07-15 23:22:37.864  INFO 47784 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2020-07-15 23:22:37.903  INFO 47784 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2020-07-15 23:22:38.041  INFO 47784 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
2020-07-15 23:22:38.249  INFO 47784 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: createUsingPOST_1
2020-07-15 23:22:38.255  INFO 47784 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: deleteByIdUsingDELETE_1
2020-07-15 23:22:38.259  INFO 47784 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: findAllUsingGET_1
2020-07-15 23:22:38.271  INFO 47784 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: findByIdUsingGET_1
2020-07-15 23:22:38.288  INFO 47784 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: searchUsingGET_1
2020-07-15 23:22:38.293  INFO 47784 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: updateUsingPUT_1
2020-07-15 23:22:38.304  INFO 47784 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: createUsingPOST_2
2020-07-15 23:22:38.310  INFO 47784 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: deleteByIdUsingDELETE_2
2020-07-15 23:22:38.654  INFO 47784 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2020-07-15 23:22:38.656  INFO 47784 --- [           main] i.i.c.CaseMarketplaceApplication         : Started CaseMarketplaceApplication in 24.351 seconds (JVM running for 24.886)
```

Currently i am using log4j which is configured via log4j2.xml like below is able to remove any useless information from startup log, but i don't know why for `springfox.documentation` its not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration strict="true" status="OFF" Log4jContextSelector="org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector">
    <appenders>           
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{yyyyMMdd:HHmmssSSS}|%-20.20thread|%5p|%-25.25logger{25}| %m%throwable%n}"/>
        </Console>
        <Console name="consoleStartup" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{yyyyMMdd:HHmmssSSS}|%-20.20thread|%5p| %m%throwable%n}"/>
        </Console>
        
    </appenders>
    <loggers>        
        <asyncLogger name="id.indexalaw.casemarketplace" level="INFO" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
            <appender-ref ref="systemAppender"/>        
        </asyncLogger>
        <asyncLogger name="access" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="accessAppender"/>        
        </asyncLogger>
        
        <!-- reqeust custom logger -->
        <logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="accessAppender"/>  
        </logger>
        
        <!-- log remover and editor-->
        <logger name="org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate" level="OFF" additivity="false"></logger>
        <logger name="springfox.documentation.spring.web.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping" level="OFF" additivity="false"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" level="OFF" additivity="false"></logger>
        <logger name="springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper" level="OFF" additivity="false"></logger>
        <logger name="springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.CachingOperationNameGenerator" level="OFF" additivity="false"></logger>

        <category name="springfox.documentation">
            <priority value="off"/>
        </category>
        <category name="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent">
            <priority value="off"/>
        </category>

        <root additivity="false" level="info" includeLocation="true">
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>        
            <appender-ref ref="systemAppender"/>              
        </root>        
    </loggers>        
</configuration>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the banner of spring and block the logger message.
In your application

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Appliocation.class);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("spring.main.banner-mode", "off");
    properties.setProperty("logging.pattern.console", "");
    application.setDefaultProperties(properties);
    application.run(args);
}
```

Or you can disable it on your Application.properties file

Here is a useful link for it: https://www.yawintutor.com/spring-boot-how-to-disable-console-log/

Comment: no i am not removing the banner, instead i want to remove all useless log from springfox.xxx.xxxxx ... and by your example above how to make it configurable from log4j2.xml?

Answer (score 1):

There is a spelling mistake in your log4j.xml, where you are turning off the logs of springfox.documentation class. The class `CachingOperationNameGenerator` has `r` spelled twice. It should be like this,

```
<logger name="springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.CachingOperationNameGenerator" level="OFF" additivity="false"></logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--关闭CachingOperationNameGenerator类日志-->
<logger name="springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.CachingOperationNameGenerator" level="OFF" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</logger>
```

it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).